# How to allow only one element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few div's that `onclick` fire a function. I want to make it so that when clicked the div that was just clicked has the class `.selected`. I then want it to be that when you click on another one of the elements, the `.selected` class is removed from the other element and then applied to the new one. When I click the first one and then click one that comes later it works fine. It is when I click the last one and then one that came before it that it just stays. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function choosediv(element){
    if(document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length != 0){
        document.getElementsByClassName('c')[0].classList.remove('selected');
    }

    element.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.c{
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
```

Comment: You just described a group of radio buttons that would be more semantically correct for the usage anyway (keep in mind you can make a radio button look like whatever you want.)

Comment: I thought about using radio buttons, but I need to have images that you click on inside the divs.

Comment: Again, using a radio input and a label element, you can do everything you want && have actual genuine a11y / aria etc compatibility but I hear ya. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are only ever removing the `selected` class from the *0th* element matched in this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('c')[0].classList.remove('selected');
```

By selecting the 0th element of the array returned by `getElementsByClassName('c')[0]`, every chosen `div` *not* at index 0 will remain selected.

You should perhaps make use of a `forEach` iteration over the elements selected by `getElementsByClassName('c')`, to remove the `selected` class from each one, rather than just the 0th one.

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove the `selected` class from the `.c` that is `.selected` (using `querySelector`, which returns the first element that matches the query, if it exists, hence the `if`), and then add `selected` class to the `element` that was clicked:

```css
.c {
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>

<script>
  function choosediv(element) {
    var curr_sel = document.querySelector('.c.selected');
    if (curr_sel) curr_sel.classList.remove('selected');
    element.classList.add('selected');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName('c')` - this will select all element that has class `c`.

you are removing only first element that has class `c` by selecting collection's element at index 0

`document.getElementsByClassName('c')[0]`

You should iterate over your collection and remove class one by one.

```
function choosediv(element){
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length > 0) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(el => {
          el.classList.remove('selected');
        })
    }

    element.classList.add('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one-liner. Just iterate over the collection of c's. When the `element` equals the one you're currently iterating, add the class, otherwise remove it:

```js
const cs = document.querySelectorAll('.c');

function choosediv(element) {
  for (const c of cs) { c.classList[c === element ? 'add' : 'remove']('selected'); }
}
```

```css
.c {
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="c" onclick="choosediv(this)">Click me</div>
```